# Emulator crashes after running code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

This is the XML file for the main fragment that i am currently dealing with. the problem i am having is that when i clean the project it does not give me any errors but when i run the program the emulator crashes.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.budgetfuel.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Select Car:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Price Per Litre:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/Space1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.66"
            android:text="Litres:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.27"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.80"
            android:text="Odo Reading:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="186dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:text="Date:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDateSet"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Change Date:" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/LinearLayout6"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Output"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is there any exception.?

Comment: Make sure you are using the `onCreateView` method to find, call your views and not `onCreate` method from your activity. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23172981/2668136), it might help you to understand.

Comment: It might be version mismatching

Comment: Make sure that your emulator version is more than api level 14, because you use space widget that works only in api 14 and above.