# imagebutton onclick new activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was searching for how to make a imagebutton that when you click on it it opens a new activity. I did it right because eclipse isn't showing any errors but when i try to run it on my xperia z and the simulator it crashes, any got a idea?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();

            ImageButton ImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search);
            ImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick (View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }    

            });
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        }

    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
05-18 15:07:10.389: I/ActivityManager(847): Start proc com.example.skatelogic for activity com.example.skatelogic/.MainActivity: pid=18106 uid=10189 gids={50189, 1028}
05-18 15:07:10.499: D/skia(18106): new locale en-Latn-US
05-18 15:07:10.529: D/AndroidRuntime(18106): Shutting down VM
05-18 15:07:10.529: W/dalvikvm(18106): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415af8b0)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.skatelogic/com.example.skatelogic.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at com.example.skatelogic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-18 15:07:10.529: E/AndroidRuntime(18106):    ... 11 more
05-18 15:07:10.529: W/ActivityManager(847):   Force finishing activity com.example.skatelogic/.MainActivity
05-18 15:07:10.829: I/WindowManager(847): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{41c6c138 ActivityRecord{4209fb70 u0 com.example.skatelogic/.MainActivity}} appWin=Window{41e5f528 u0 Starting com.example.skatelogic} drawState=4
05-18 15:07:10.829: W/WindowManager(847): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (1080x1920) to layer 21025
05-18 15:07:10.920: I/CrashMonitor(14341): CrashMonitorServiceBroadcastReceiver: Forwarding intent: android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED tag: data_app_crash
05-18 15:07:10.930: I/CrashMonitor(14341): CrashMonitorService: Service started...
```

Comment: Post the logcat. It might crash caused by a NullPointerException on `ImageButton` or into the Intent where `SearchActivity` isn't declared in the Manifest. We cannot help without know what error is.

Comment: post your `logcat` it would be helpful for us

Comment: I added it, if i added it wrong tell me

Comment: You have a NullPointerException at `ImageButton ImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search);`. Do you create the view inside `fragment_main.xml` or `acitvity_main.xml`? Also make sure in the layout the ImageButton has the right id as `search`.

Comment: i created it in fragment_main and i have the right id

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23172981/2668136) to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @Fllo commented, the NPE is caused because the `ImageButton` is declared as part of the `PlaceHolderFragment`; at `Activity.onCreate()` the root view of the `Fragment` hasn't been attached to the activity's view tree yet.

If you retain the instance of `PlaceHolderFragment`, you can get the root view, and then find the search icon from there:

```
PlaceHolderFragment fragment = new PlaceHolderFragment();
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.search);
```

That is, you'll use `View.findViewById()`, rather than `Activity.findViewById()`.

---

I prefer this approach over moving the OnClickListener to the Fragment because they're just convenient containers for a set of Views; apart from knowing that they live inside an Activity, ideally they don't know anything else (including *which* Activity they are inside); they should be as self-contained as possible to allow reuse in different Activities and by starting Activities from a Fragment, it suggests it knows too much about its context.

Comment: Thank you and @fiLlo for a quick reply!