# App has stopped working - Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I tried searching on similar questions but couldn't get what I wanted. I tried reading the logs and searched for `CAUSED BY:` and this is what I got:

```
caused by : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int counter;
    Button add,sub;
    TextView display;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        sub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter = counter +1;
                display.setText("your total is "+ counter);
                                        }
            });
sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter = counter -1;
        display.setText("your total is "+ counter);
                                }
        });
     }
```

and the xml file:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ref"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="40sp"
/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:text="@string/refbut1"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_below= "@+id/button1"
android:text="@string/refbut2"
    />
```

activity main xml file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/container"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.liall.tutorialfrominternet.MainActivity"
 tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Comment: Do you have an inner fragment in this Activity, Liall? Can you post the full logcat or tell us which line occurs a NPE?

Comment: Make sure the Buttons and the TextView are in `/res/layout/activity_main.xml`

Comment: I am sorry I started programming a few days ago what is NPE? And k I will post full logcat.

Comment: NPE = NullPointerException (Sorry about that).

Comment: I did not use activity main xml file at all. I will post its content.

Comment: I think it's the cause of the issue. You might [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23172981/2668136) to understand. You have to play with the inner fragment (`PlaceholderFragment`) or put all your views inside `activity_main.xml` and remove the fragment.

Comment: Floo oh yeah that might be the problem. Thank you very much I will check that out ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Next time you posting a question please provide the full crash log so that we would at least know in what line you get the exception.

`NullPointerException` is an Exception of type `NullPointerException`, the jvm will through this exception when a reference is being made for an object that wasn't initialized or was initialized with null value.

In this example the you did initialized add and sub buttons but still got NPE on one of them. 
The code is fine so the problem's source probably arise from an environment point of view,

1. Did you clean and build your project before you ran it? probably the xml weren't generated yet, sometimes clean and build force regenerating of the resources, updating the R file and solve resource's related bugs.
2. What is the first xml you posted? why doesn't it a child of the rooted `FrameLayout` in `activity_main`?